# How to encode German characters in requests-response from website correctly?

Tags: python, web-scraping, encoding, python-requests

I want to extract data from transfermarkt.de. For fetching the data I use the requests library. But no matter what encoding I use, the German special characters are not parsed correctly.

The site gives UTF-8 as encoding in the header, but the automatic encoding in requests puts out wrong special characters. By comparing I found out, that r.text looks absolutely the same as r.content when using UTF-8.

So I read a lot about encoding (yes, I think I get the Unicode-thing now ;-)) and tried different encodings with requests - here's my test-code:

```
import requests

link = 'https://www.transfermarkt.de/fc-bayern-munchen/kader/verein/27/saison_id/2017'        
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'


r=requests.get(link, headers={"User-Agent":user_agent})

print('---------------------------------CONTENT----------')
print(r.content[4500:5000])

r.encoding = 'UTF-8'
print('-------------------------------TEXT UTF8----------')
print(r.text[4500:5000])

r.encoding = 'iso-8859-1'
print('--------------------------------TEXT iso-8859-1----------')
print(r.text[4500:5000])
```

This gives the following output:

```
-----------------------------------------CONTENT----------
FC Bayern M├╝nchen - Kader im Detail 17/18" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//css/stylesheets/menue.css?lm=1556636907" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/c
-----------------------------------------TEXT iso-8859-1----------
FC Bayern M├â┬╝nchen - Kader im Detail 17/18" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//css/stylesheets/menue.css?lm=1556636907" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/c
-----------------------------------------TEXT UTF8----------
Bayern M├╝nchen - Kader im Detail 17/18" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//css/stylesheets/menue.css?lm=1556636907" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
```

As you can see, the "ü" of "München" is not shown correctly in the excerpt. Does anybody have a clue, what I could do differently?

Comment: Try writing the output in a file and reading it later, instead of doing it on the terminal. Or just redirect the output to a file. Maybe the problem is with the terminals UTF handling.

Comment: I tried it too. UTF-8 worked. There was München.

Comment: Looks like you're right. This worked, thanks!